# Rotate a node so it points to a specific position in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I have a node and I want it's peak point to a specific position (coordinates). How can I do that? So far, I have tried noting because I have no clue how can I do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to [SCNConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNConstraint_Class/index.html), and more specifically `SCNLookAtConstraint`.

There are a few similar questions on StackOverflow and examples in both SceneKit WWDC demos.

Next time you ask a question here, make sure you have a specific problem, and do as much research as you can. Show you did all of that, and you won't get downvoted!

If you encounters problems with the constraints, make sure to check if [it has been asked here first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SCNLookAtConstraint). Good luck!